# Cordova Android build FAILED after Android Studio3.5 update

Tags: gradle, cordova-android

I've updated Android Studio **`3.5`** some days ago. BTW, I've got failed to build **cordova android** with the following verbose:

> Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a solution from other stars' prior answers.

The **reason** is due to missing of [Gradle](https://gradle.org/install/) installation. Android Studio 3.5 doesn't update or install `Gradle` as its dependency so that we should install it manually.

#### for Windows users

1. Download **Gradle 5.6** zip installer [here](https://gradle.org/releases/).
2. Create a new directory `C:\Gradle` with File Explorer.

   Open a second File Explorer window and go to the directory where the **Gradle** distribution was downloaded. Double-click the ZIP archive to expose the content. Drag the content folder `gradle-5.6` to your newly created `C:\Gradle` folder.
3. Configure your system environment.

   In File Explorer right-click on the `This PC` (or `Computer`) icon, then click `Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environmental Variables`.

   Under `System Variables` select Path, then click Edit. Add an entry for `C:\Gradle\gradle-5.6\bin`. Click OK to save.
4. Verify your installation

   `$ gradle -v`
5. Restart your terminal and try build `cordova-android` again.

   It will run success.

Thanks for attention.

Comment: this is nothing new... it's not specific to AS 3.5, which `cordova` does not even use.

Comment: @MartinZeitler gradle will be used by cordova to build apk right ? (ionic 1).

Comment: @Ali the other alternative is to used the android studio installed gradle wrapper which is reside at C:\Users\xxx\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.4.1-all\3221gyojl5jsh0helicew7rwx\gradle-5.4.1\bin . I also encounter this issue after updating AS to 3.5.0

Comment: @cumibulat of course it build with Gradle... and that `cordova` doesn't find the wrapper and is easier to setup with a stand-alone Gradle install is what I've meant with "nothing new".

Comment: @MartinZeitler i see.. thanks for the reply. will noted about it.

Comment: Just for clarification: I also had the same issue after updating AS from 3.2 to 3.5 (I don't use it often, so I hadn't updated in ages), but *did* AS previously include Gradle and now it doesn't? Or is there a different reason that updating to 3.5 might cause this? FWIW, I also fixed my issue by installing Gradle manually, whereas I didn't need to previously.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is that build variants must choose debug mode.